# Sql query for selecting entries with today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have the following table in sql server 2008 (Called "act_events"):

[image]

As you notice some of the datetimes are formated: "yyyy-mm-dd" and some: "yyyy-dd-mm" for some weird reason I still haven't figured..

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT * from act_events
WHERE '2013-07-30'>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) AND 
      '2013-07-30'<=(CAST(e_end as DATE))
```

Where I want to select events only with today's date.

But I can't figure a way to select both formats..

I tries this query:

```
SELECT * from act_events 
WHERE( @date1>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) AND
        @date2<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) ) OR
      ( @date3>=(CAST(e_start as DATE)) AND
        @date4<=(CAST(e_end as DATE)) )
```

But it only works for certain dates..

Would appreciate your answers.

**Also, if there's a statement that will change all datetime to correct format I would love to hear.**

Comment: To me, and most likely to SQL server, all dates seem to be formatted yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: @Recipe I thought that, but then you have 2013-01-08 following 2013-07-16. I think that OP has an issue differentiating between UK and US date formats.

Comment: Yes from the sample there doesn't seem to be any reason to believe the formats are mixed. BUT if they are I'd suggest a data cleaning exercise rather than doing what you are talking about. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Recipe they are by default. You can change it though.

Comment: @Dvirski - Fix your dates separately. Don't work around a problem by introducing further complexity.

Comment: The formats are mixed, because last date's month is august

Comment: 2 different dateformats ? I assume this is not a datetime, which would be impossible. So assuming it is a varchar(23) ish. Which date would '2012-02-01' be in your compare ?

Comment: @Dvirski then you have bad dates in the system.  SQL doesn't store the dates in a certain format - it just stores the data representing that date.  2013-03-08 in the query results above is March 8th, not August 3rd.  I suspect whatever is _adding_ those dates is formatting it as a string and not as a datetime.

Comment: @Dvirski Are the columns of type DateTime or are they something else? This entire discussion depends on that.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Exactly my thoughts. But you should be thinking the way SQLserver is think: in one date format. For the machine, everything seems normal.

Comment: @ObieMD5 I know this. See my post above. In my opinion, this is something that the user has to fix as well in order to get a correct solution...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dates are indeed of type `DateTime`, what you could do in this case is to use dateadd and datediff.

Run these two statements:

```
-- Todays date, date part only
select dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()))
-- Tomorrows date, date part only
select dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, dateadd(dd, 1, getdate())))
```

Using those two, you can do this (Including edits, thanks @gvee)

```
select *
from act_events 
where 
        e_start >= dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())) 
    and 
        e_end < dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()) + 1)
```

I should mention that `getdate()` is a built-in function in SQL Server. You could of course change this to a variable if you are using this in a stored procedure for example.

As a side note, the date in SQL Server is actually a number. The format that comes out when you look at it is for humans and humans are not to be trusted, right?

Comment: You should be using `WHERE e_start >= <lower_date> AND e_start < <upper_date`. Otherwise the next day at exactly midnight will be included in the results.

Comment: Furthermore you can simplify the last part to be `DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, GetDate()) + 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select *

from t 
where 
   CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)=substring(date_c,1,4)
       +substring(date_c,6,2)
       +substring(date_c,9,2)
   or
   CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)=substring(date_c,1,4)
       +substring(date_c,9,2)
       +substring(date_c,6,2)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b847f/5)

Comment: the desired date goes where the numbers are? how exactly?

Comment: @Dvirski [CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 112)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) converts date to `YYYYMMDD` format so today we get `20130730` now we have to compose this string from given varchar dates in your table `substring(date_c,1,4)+substring(date_c,6,2)+substring(date_c,9,2)` and `substring(date_c,1,4)+substring(date_c,9,2)+substring(date_c,6,2)` for different date presentations 'YYYY-MM-DD' and 'YYYY-DD-MM'